# Using the magnetic masses model how do i find the induced magnetic field due to a magnetic point charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I am deriving an equation modelling a magnetic guitar pickup and I am stuck.

I am trying to derive based on a paper for guitar pickups and it uses a magnetic masses method to find the magnetic flux at point c from magnetic field generated by point a and steel point b. I am confused where the integral comes from:
[image]

These papers uses the same method https://www.dafx17.eca.ed.ac.uk/papers/DAFx17_paper_79.pdf
https://scholarship.rollins.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1014&context=stud_fac

EDIT:
Apologies to clarify my question more I am trying to understand where this three point integral comes from in this section of the papers shown above.
[image]

Comment: I think that in order for people to help you better, you could, for example ,add more info on a magnetic guitar, what is that? Also, it is not clear what equation you want to derive, what physical phenomena does it model, do you talk about a magnetic field vs distance or something else?

Comment: I have edited my question. I am confused about where the three part integral comes from.